In multiprocessor systems do interrupts block all execution?
I have read you are not supposed to use a blocking system call in an interrupt handler.
For single processor systems this makes sense but, for multiprocessor systems will such a blocking operation truly block the whole system? Or only the processor it runs on?

a blocking function simply loops until something happens ... it will block any processor that runs it ... so you have to determine which processors are servicing the interrupt

So if you're OK with losing a processor during the interrupt, a blocking interrupt won't freeze the whole system?

I do not have much experience with processors... I am simply using logic to make the comment ... it makes no sense that anyone would design a multi-processor system that completely halts when a single interrupt is received, other than a reset

Are you talking about a signal handler in a program, or are you talking about an interrupt handler in the kernel?

Interrupt handler in kernel.

Based on: https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch10.pdf
When an interrupt is received by the processor, it first runs a bit of architecture-specific assembler code, then jumps to do_IRQ: a part of interrupt handler code that is common to all interrupts.
From the paragraph The internals of interrupt handling on the x86 (page 11 of the link above):

The first thing do_IRQ does is to acknowledge the interrupt so that the interrupt controller can go on to other things. It then obtains a spinlock for the given IRQ number,thus preventing any other CPU from handling this IRQ.

So the interrupt controller is allowed to generate another instance of the same interrupt, but any processor that would attempt to handle it would be blocked by a spinlock until the current instance of the interrupt is handled. In other words, other processors/cores are not blocked from executing code: they are just blocked from entering the same interrupt handler that is now executing on the current core. And the blocking is with a spinlock, so the expectation is that the required wait will be very short.
A blocking system call is one that involves waiting for something to happen: while waiting, the processor can be (and normally is) scheduled to run other tasks.
But if the current core (that is executing an interrupt handler) gets scheduled to run other tasks/processes, the spinlock it's holding is left locked. And there is no guarantee that the context that started the interrupt handler would be scheduled for execution again in a reasonable time. Meanwhile, if the same interrupt is signaled again, any processor attempting to handle it will be held in the spinlock. Unless the interrupt-context-that-waited is promptly scheduled for execution again, completes the interrupt processing and unlocks the spinlock, there is a risk that all cores will end up trapped by the spinlock, completely deadlocking the system.
Therefore, a core that is running an interrupt handler must not be scheduled to other tasks until the interrupt handler is done. A higher-tier interrupt may pre-empt the current interrupt context, but once that is done, the core must return to complete the interrupt handler as promptly as possible.
And so, the "not supposed to use a blocking system call in an interrupt handler" is really just a subset of "you must not cause a core to be scheduled to other tasks while it's executing an interrupt handler".
(Historically, when Linux started as a single-processor OS, there used to be a one and only Big Kernel Lock that was used to control access to many parts of the kernel. When multi-processor support was added, this soon became a performance-limiting issue, and much effort was spent to transitioning away from the Big Kernel Lock, to either lockless methods whenever possible, and to more fine-grained locking otherwise.)

Do you know if there is a way to easily control this? IE dedicate one core to handling a time sensitive interrupt which blocks until a certain time has passed?

When an interrupt arrives, the core must switch to the appropriate interrupt context and push the previous state into the stack (of the interrupt context) anyway, so it essentially makes no difference whether the core was idle or busy before that. If a particular interrupt is especially time-sensitive, it should only need protection from other, higher-tier interrupts - which you can do using SMP affinities of the IRQs. You can also use e.g. taskset to make regular processes avoid such a dedicated core if you wish.
